# Memory leak when reading data file

Tags: python, memory-leaks, readfile, memory-profiling

I wrote a script to import data from a (quite messy) datafile. Each line is read and processed separately in a loop.

I wrote the following code to skip the header and white lines:

```
for line in rd_file.readlines(): 
    line_1 = line.rstrip("\n")                                            
    # Decide what to do based on the content in the line.                    
    if "#" in line.lower(): 
        header_flag=True
        # Don't print the header  
        pass
    elif line.strip() == "":                                     
        pass
    else:       
        [...]
```

Running the script I noticed a memory leak. I located it using [memory_profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler) and I found out it is due to:

```
elif line.strip() == "": 
  pass
```

This is what I get from `memory_profiler`:

```
45    204.5 MiB    160.6 MiB           elif line.strip() == ""
```

How is it possible that 160 MB get occupied just by skipping a blank line? Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: How big is the data file?

Comment: I suspect you're using the profiler incorrectly.

Comment: How big are the individual lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend not invoking readlines(), but instead depend on the python file iterator pattern.

```
for line in rd_file:
    line_1 = line.rstrip("\n")   
    ...
```

Comment: I had to use readlines because I am dealing with an spt file, and if I use `for line in rd_file:` I get the error `for line in rd_file(): 
TypeError: 'file' object is not callable`. Let me know if you have suggestions on how to fix this

Comment: You made a typo. Loose the parens after rd_file. Using file objects in an iterator pattern is well documented in the python docs.

Comment: Right. I made the suggested change, but that didn't fix the leak.

Comment: I need to see more of the code. I'm using the pattern I described above in project right now that walks over a 20-GB text file with no problems. It might also be useful to know what your doing with the read file contents ... you're not storing it in some sort of memory buffer are you?

Comment: I made a few changes and re-profiled the code. Probably the leak is due to OpenCV, which I am using to load tif images using `cv2.imread`: it looks like the garbage collector doesn't clean the image files, which are kept in memory.